# Проблема с активацией виртуальной среды в pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, powershell

Недавно обновил компьютер и поставил 11 винду, запустил проект и пошли проблемы с венвом. Как понял, что это связано с шеллом.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18713086/7753445